# How can i see the SQL Server queries coming from my program?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this c# web app that relies heavily on two dll files that i can't see nor edit. The rest of the app is visible and editable.

The app generates SQL exceptions, and i would like to see the queries sent from the DLLs. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Which database?: answers are about SQL Server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) to see the queries that goes to your database.

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server 2005/2008 Express you can try [AnjLab's SQL Profiler](http://sqlprofiler.googlepages.com/).

Comment: I tried  this one just recently for a SQL express installation and it does the job very well i must say.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see what is running is SP_WHO2 'active' combined with DBCC INPUTBUFFER(SPID) or query the [sys.dm_exec_requests].

The SQL Profiler mentioned above is the preferred method.